# How to handle Custom error pages for 500 error in kohana 3.3

Tags: error-handling, custom-error-pages, kohana-3.3

How to use custom error pages for 500 error in kohana 3.3. I have tried using the custom error pages for 404 error and its working. I have just refered [kohana official site](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/tutorials/error-pages) but i have no idea how to handle 500 error. It will be really helpful if someone help on this. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You must override HTTP_Exception_500 class

```
class HTTP_Exception_500 extends Kohana_HTTP_Exception_500 {

    public function get_response()
    {
        //your code like in official guide by 404 page
    }
}
```

path of class - APPPATH/classes/HTTP/Exception/500.php

Comment: Yes, it works for 404, for example. But if I want to do a redirect inside, how should I do ? HTTP::redirect('...',302); > return me an error... "Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 302 ]:" and no message.